# Issues with .htaccess friendly urls and with mod_rewrite enabled

Tags: php, linux, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Dealing with a issue getting friendly urls to work on my server, i'm using .htaccess for it and mod_rewrite is enabled.

For an example changing www.mydomain.com/about.php to www.mydomain.com/about

This is my current .htaccess code but all i get on www.mydomain.com/about is "Page Not Found".

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

 RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]

# BEGIN non-www to www 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.mydomain\.com)?$ 
 RewriteRule (.*) https://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L] 

 ErrorDocument 404 https://www.mydomain.com/404
 ErrorDocument 500 https://www.mydomain.com/500
 </IfModule>
```

Is there anything you notice?, or any ideas why it's not working correctly?.

Comment: How is it not working correctly?

Comment: "Page not found" friendly url it's not working as described above, any ideas ?. Have edited the description to make this more clear...

Comment: I guess that `AllowOverride` is set to `None` in your directory context and the `.htaccess` is not processed at all. Set `AllowOverride All` within the directory context and the redirect should work (at least the about.php to about part).

Comment: Verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting same garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not?